# Mapping Android device models to human-readable brand names

Tags: android

I need to find the brand name of an Android device device models (such as "Samsung Galaxy S III").

Unfortunately, `android.os.Build.MODEL` returns the model name, such as GT-I9300. There is no way to get a human-readable brand name, so in order to show a human-readable name, such as "Galaxy S III", I apparently need to manually map all the Android device models in the world.

Where can I find a complete list of devices with a mapping, or a better solution for this mapping issue?

Comment: I've found a pretty good list at https://github.com/meetup/android-device-names/blob/master/android_models.properties

Comment: Thank you, @espinchi. This is the best list I've seen so far.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This info is widely available, you can get from google as part of their answer "Full list of supported devices": https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1727131 -> https://storage.googleapis.com/support-kms-prod/21707874A6E6F72ECEE9DCF33F867D25035B

Linked PDF mirrored here: https://www.scribd.com/doc/248834602/List-of-Supported-Android-Devices

Answer (score 0):

There is a CSV file published by google which contains the list of all the recognized phones by google.

So I created a library using that CSV file to easily get the Name of the Device

Here is how it works
The library is https://github.com/aishik212/AndroidPhoneNamesFinder

You can get the device name via the following method

Add this to gradle

```
implementation 'com.github.aishik212:AndroidPhoneNamesFinder:v1.0.2'
```

Then use the following

```
DeviceNameFinder.getPhoneValues(this, object : DeviceDetailsListener {

    override fun details(doQuery: DeviceDetailsModel?) 
    {  
        super.details(doQuery)  
        Log.d(TAG, "details: "+doQuery?.calculatedName)  
    }   
})
```

Here to get the calculated name that is the most expected name use the calculatedName variable.

Comment: Where is the CSV?

Comment: i don't use csv , i convert to to a db file manually via online tools, will automate this in the future